# Creating an 'index' of current files in a given folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, directory

I want to create a webpage which looks something like this:

```
<h1>Index of Results</h1>

<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='result1.html'>--Result 1--</a></li>
        <li><a href='result2.html'>--Result 2--</a></li>
        <li><a href='... </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

where the `results` are updated on this page every time there is a new file added to a folder/directory.

Is it possible to monitor a folder/ directory using something like JavaScript and update this list without having to hard-code all the links & tags etc?

Comment: Something like a `foreach` loop may be useful.

Comment: Do you understand the javascript sandbox? Javascript cannot access the users environment (except the user grants it (camera etc). You could upload a folder, but to index a folder on your harddrive you need to use another language/environment ( php,java,c for example)

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, I understand that JavaScript does not have access to the user files, hence why I wrote `something like Javascript` (as ambiguous as it sounds)... would you be able to show me how to achieve this using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a PHP solution:

```
<?php
print_r(scandir("/folder"));
?>
```

You could also apply your own html to it:

```
<?php
$files=scandir("/folder");
foreach($files as $file){
echo "<p>". $file."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!